# Insert a widget outside widget Dialog - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this design
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XJ9j.png) and I'm trying to reproduce it on Flutter.

I already managed to reproduce everything less the text below the Dialog Box. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSjvh.png)
How do I insert the Texts outside dialog box?

My Dialog without text inside the DialogBox.

```
Dialog(
 insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, left: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 170),
 shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
 elevation: 0,
 child: Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: Container(
   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 16),
   width: 340,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: ThemeColor.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
   ),
  ),
 ),
)
```

Comment: I think you can  wrap it inside column

Comment: I already tried that. But either the object doesn’t leave the white box or when it does, they have double yellow lines below

Answer (score 0):

You can use Overlay with the dialog to show that effect

```
const String title = 'Recurring Billing, cancel anytime. \n';
const String paragraph = '''By Tapping Continue, your payment will be charged to your Google Play account, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
''';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}


class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  OverlayEntry _overlayEntry; // The Overlay

  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    //Overlay is a Stack, so you can use Positiioned or Align,
    //play with the values to position the best you can the text
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Positioned(
        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        child: RichText(
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.parent,
            text: TextSpan(
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              text: title,
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  text: paragraph
                )
              ]
            ),
          )
      )
    );
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Tap'),
      onPressed: () async{
        _overlayEntry = _createOverlayEntry(); //create the Overlay
        Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayEntry); //The overlay state
        //await for the future Dialog to end, basically until pop
        await showDialog(
         context: context,
         builder: (context) {
           return Dialog(
              insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, left: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 170),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              elevation: 0,
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 16),
                  width: 340,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        );
        _overlayEntry.remove(); //remove the overlay after the dialog pop
      }
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, it is more simple using only [Overflow Box](https://flutter-widget.live/widgets/OverflowBox)

[image]

```dart
class OverflowDialogBox extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      insetPadding:
          EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, left: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 170),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      elevation: 0,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 16),
          width: 340,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Text("text\n\n\n\ntext\n\n\n\n"),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 1.0,
                  height: 1.0,
                  child: OverflowBox(
                    minWidth: 0.0,
                    maxWidth: 1000.0,
                    minHeight: 0.0,
                    maxHeight: 250.0,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: 1.0,
                          height: 1.0,
                          child: OverflowBox(
                            minWidth: 0.0,
                            maxWidth: 1000.0,
                            minHeight: 0.0,
                            maxHeight: 80.0,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.black38,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Recurring Billing, Cancel Anytime",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```